# Executing lua scripts from java

Tags: java, lua

How would I go about executing a lua script from some directory from java that can get and set values in the calling object?

For example:

```
public SomeJavaClass
{
    public int someInt;

    public SomeJavaClass(int i)
    {
        this.someInt = i;
    }

    public void runLuaScript(String script)
    {
        executeSomeLuaScriptSomehow(script);
    }

    public int getSomeInt()
    {
        return someInt;
    }

    public void setSomeInt(int i)
    {
        this.someInt = i;
    }
}
```

And then in SomeLuaScript.lua

```
if javaParent.getSomeInt() > 3 then
    javaParent.setSomeInt(1)
end
```

Comment: `runLuaScript()` Will recurse infinitely. ..

Comment: Just an example, clarified it a bit to show it's some other function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LuaJava](http://www.keplerproject.org/luajava/) library allows java to run Lua Scripts, and vice versa.

Comment: Hmm, that seems like it could do everything I need. I'll check it out